# Will removed default apps come back after an upgrade to a new release?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, release-management

I long removed Firefox, Evolution, Brasero and other apps that originally came with Maverick. Will the upgrade bring them back? If so is there a way to prevent this? Also, will other 3rd party apps still work even if they're based on Maverick dependencies? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the removed default application will not come back but the new default applications will be installed.

There are two cases:

1. When the default application is the same between upgrade it will not be installed e.g. Evolution between 10.10 and 11.04
2. When the default application has been changed e.g. 11.04 the default media player is changed from RhythmBox (10.10) to Banshee so even if you have removed RhythmBox, Banshee will still be installed.

The answer is based on my upgrade to 11.04 from 10.10

Comment: This is what I meant: "I removed Evolution, will it be back after the upgrade"? I assume in this case the answer is yes, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, it will not as Evolution is still the default application. I will edit my answer to just keep it simple :)